# Не получается вывести в ответ переменные, чтобы каждая была на своей строке

Tags: python

Только начал изучать питон, поэтому прошу без сложностей.
Имею вот такой код:

```
a = str(input())
d = len(a)
b = str()
while d != 0:
    b += a
    a = str(input())
    d = len(a)
print(b)
```

При вводе x y z он выводит xyz, а надо чтобы каждая переменная с новой строки.Вот само задание: Пользователь вводит строки одну за другой до тех пор, пока не введёт пустую. Программа должна выводить введенные строки, пока не встретилась пустая.
Помогите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?

Comment: не складывайте строки в b, а сразу выводите.  И лишние преобразования в str уберите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` - команда в Python, которая возвращает строку, введённую пользователем до первого символа переноса строки `'\n'`.
К примеру для команды `a = input()` при введении `'x'` и нажатию клавиши Enter в переменную a будет введён лишь символ x без символа `'\n'`.

```
>>>a = input()
x
>>>a
'x'
```

Как видите, никаких `'\n'`. 
Результат команды `input()` - объект класса `str`, поэтому нет смыссла писать `a = str(input())`. Пишите просто `a = input()`.
Для реализации вашей задумки можно написать так:

```
a = input()
d = len(a)
b = str()
while d != 0:
    b += a + '\n'
    a = input()
    d = len(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    a = input("Введите переменную (выход Enter): ")
    if not a:
        break
    print("Вы ввели переменную: {}".format(a))
```